# Reading in variables from a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, environment-variables

Is there a way to read in a file of environment variables?

In bash I have a file env.sh that I can use

env.sh

```
foo="bar"
```

bash file

```
set -a
source env.sh
```

This would allow me to just use foo as if I had delcared it in the ruby script.

Also is it there a way to make sure that this file is unreadable so that passwords could be stored in this file?

Comment: Parsing a file of name/value pairs is easy. What have you tried? And, you want to make the file unreadable to who?

Comment: @theTinMan I have not tried anything yet for the file, I did a quick google search and nothing was matching exactly what I was looking for so that is why I asked if it was possible and unreadable to anyone who is not the owner of the file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you should provide a file example for the user/admin to modify for their personal environment, and then populate the environment from that, while avoiding, perhaps, having that file with the sensitive information in a repository.  Note: per file security is going to be addressed by where the file is located and your operating system, and server software.

If this is the case, then you can provide a file that holds a template of the kind of things that you would require from the administrator/user of the program you are configuring.

Ruby has the `ENV` constant that acts like a `Hash` and holds the environment of the shell you are using.

As an example, there is a file called environment.rb.sample that gets shared with anyone, publicly.  It has instructions and holds the template that users can modify freely, with instructions to copy the file to `environment.rb`.  The sample file looks like this:

```
# environment.rb.sample
# Copy this file to environment.rb and change the name and password to your credentials
ENV['temp_user_name'] = 'Foo Bar'
ENV['temp_password'] = 'Dazz Kezz
```

The file is then copied to this, perhaps:

```
# environment.rb
ENV['temp_user_name'] = 'Joe Admin'
ENV['temp_password'] = 'Super Secure Password'
```

The file that loads this and uses it is just a Ruby file that is freely modified by the user/administrator of the software, and looks like this and is also shared publicly.

```
# load_environment
require './environment'
puts ENV['temp_user_name']
puts ENV['temp_password']
```

This loads the file and uses the `ENV` that is a globally scoped constant for the application.

The file permissions are then managed by the user/administrator of the system and secured like any other sensitive information on their system.  The sensitive file should also be listed in the repository's ignore mechanism.  It should never be made public.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is, and if for some bizzare, arcane reason you must use it, it's eval:

## WARNING: *Never* use this on a user-supplied file

**And, unless you have a very, very specific need, don't use it in production code.**

```
eval(File.read("name_of_var_file"), binding)
```

---

If what you're really trying to do is write a configuration file, use YAML. A file like this:

config.yaml:

```
foo: "bar"
```

Can be accessed like this:

```
require 'yaml'
conf = YAML.loads(File.read("config.yaml"))
conf['foo'] #=> 'bar'
```

This is secure and manageable, not to mention standard practice.

---

As for making the file inaccessible, that is an operating system level problem that can't be solved without information on the environment, OS, setup, etc.

Comment: Why should I not use the eval out of curiosity?

Comment: Why not to use eval from a user supplied file is actually due to the risk involved.  There is quite a bit of information about this on the internet.  And probably here on SO. Or Security Exchange.

Comment: This also simply does not address the environment variable part of the question.

Comment: @vgoff: Then what about this part of the question: "This would allow me to just use foo as if I had delcared it in the ruby script." ?

Comment: That would be fine, if it was placed in the environment hash.  But you don't. The weight comes from the very first sentence of the question: "Is there a way to read in a file of environment variables?"

Comment: @vgoff: everything s an environment variable in bash.

Comment: OK, sure, but not in Ruby.

Comment: I used the eval method above and it worked, but I had to declare the variables in irb before calling eval.  I was loading an array of stored data for testing purposes.

Comment: The `eval` method is perfect for my context. I am doing a one-time data migration and put everything into a giant array in a file. `eval` lets me read the data from the file. I wouldn't use it on any file that I do not have complete control over the content.

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi: Absolutely; especially in scripting contexts it can be a very useful tool. Still, I hold that there are almost no reasons to use `eval` in production code, as it introduces an enormous degree of potential complexity and makes it much harder to reason about a piece of code, sometimes in ways that are very subtle and escape even an experienced developer.

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi: I've made another edit; do you think that sounds like a reasonable compromise? Thanks for taking the time to refine this answer.

Comment: @Linuxios yes, :) and you're also welcome to put it back to how it was - it's you're answer

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a local variable is to be used temporally within a method definition or a block. Using it outside of such environments, particularly across files defeats the purpose of it. You should not need to do it, and Ruby does not have a simple way to do it.

If you are using variables correctly, and want to share variables between files, that should be other types of variables such as instance, class, or global variables. Or, for the purpose of setting environments, you should be using constants. Among them, global variables and constants can be written in a file, loaded in a different file, and be used.

file-a.rb

```
$foo = 1
FOO = 2
```

file-b.rb

```
load "file-a.rb"
$foo # => 1
FOO # => 2
```

As for instance and class variables, they belong to a class or an instance of it, so they should be defined in such environment. And you can reopen the same class within a different file, and load it in another file.

file-a.rb

```
class Bar
  @@foo = 1
  def initialize; @foo = 2 end
end
```

file-b.rb

```
load "file-a.rb"
Bar.class_variable_get("@@foo") # => 1
Bar.new.instance_variable_get("@foo") # => 2
```

Comment: That makes sense, I was trying to keep passwords and such out of my program and that is why I was trying to load them in that way. This is just a script and I am not planning it to have any classes in it